# How to copy file contents to the local clipboard from a file in a remote machine over ssh

Tags: ssh, clipboard

To solve this problem I always have to use `scp` or `rsync` to copy the file into my local computer to open the file and simply copy the contents of the text file into my local clipboard. I was just wondering if there is a more clever way to do this without having the need of copying the file.

Comment: I changed the title a bit, because I kept the reading "the local clipboard of a file" and wondering since when files had clipboards.

Comment: Thats fine thanks @Anthon English is not my first language so sometimes I need some help with it thanks.

Comment: When all else fails (e.g. you are going through jumphosts), just one other option: use `nl catalina.out` which prefixes each line with numbers so you can be sure you don't miss any out with mouse highlighting to copy and paste.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Of course you have to read the file, but you could

```
</dev/null ssh USER@REMOTE "cat file" | xclip -i
```

though that still means to open a ssh connection and copy the contents of the file. But finally you don't see anything of it anymore ;)

And if you are connecting from an OS X computer you use `pbcopy` instead:

```
</dev/null ssh USER@REMOTE "cat file" | pbcopy
```

PS: Instead of `</dev/null` you can use `ssh -n` but I don't like expressing things in terms of software options, where I can use the system to get the same.

PPS: The `</dev/null` pattern for ssh is extremely usefull for loops

```
printf %s\\n '-l user host1' '-l user host2' | while read c
do </dev/null ssh $u "ip address; hostname; id"
done
```

Comment: This is great, I though this wasn't possible. Although I had to use pbcopy because I'm connecting from a mac computer to a CentOS box. I just had to change xclip to pbcopy and it worked. Pretty nice!

Comment: `-e none` would only be need to prevent the special handling of `~` **from the keyboard** (not from the output of commands) in interactive sessions only. It's not needed here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas you are right. Today I would use `</dev/null ssh USER@REMOTE "cat file"` Though this `</dev/null` is not needed, it might be usefull in loops, or in background operations. There is also the option -n, but if you don't go interactive, you should use such a `</dev/null` pattern!

Comment: @ikrabbe —  I am not exactly sure what the purpose of `</del/null` is and why it is to the left of the `ssh` command. Do you mind clarifying/explaining a bit? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel yes, that is easy: The `</dev/null` is the input of the process (here ssh), which otherwise would wait. When you do the ssh on the command line, this looks equal to not giving any input, but in loops of several ssh commands, this is needed, so it is a good vritue to give it always. It is just a question of taste to put it on the left. I do this to express `<INPUT PROCESS | OUTPUT` logic, where the INPUT is on the left. You can also do PROCESS <INPUT | OUTPUT, but that looks ugly to me.

Comment: @ikrabbe — I had never seen the input to the left of the process so I assumed your example was showing a requirement. Thank you for clarifying how it works and that it works either way, and that it was just your preference to do that way instead of a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Using Putty as your SSH client, ensure you max out lines of scrollback in your configuration.  When you connect, you can clear screen and scrollback and then cat the file and when I right click on the title bar, I can select "copy all to clipboard".  Then I can paste into an editor on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Can I assume you are running the X Window System and some window manager (KDE/gnome/etc.)? There are a number of terminal applications (Konsole for example) that have a built in menu that allows copy/paste functions. 
So you could:

1. user@machine:~$ ssh root@172.x.x.x
2. open the file on the remote machine
3. highlight the contents of the file with mouse and select copy from the edit menu on your local machine.

Or did I misunderstand your real needs?

Comment: I could do this with small files but with big files if I try to scroll up or down it goes off of the file (you can try it for yourself to see that this approach not always work.)

Comment: with big files, you can take more time on copy than rewrite the script manually in the local editor xD

Answer (score 0):

[Far Manager Linux port](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l) supports synchronizing clipboard between local and remote host. You just open local far2l, do "ssh somehost" inside, run remote far2l in that ssh session and get remote far2l working with your local clipboard.

It supportes Linux, *BSD and OS X; I made a [special putty build](https://github.com/unxed/putty4far2l) to utilize this functionality from windows also.