# Copy the contents of a file into the clipboard without displaying its contents

Tags: file-copy

How to copy the contents of a file in UNIX without displaying the file contents. I don't want to cat or vi to see the contents.

I want to copy them to clipboard so that I can paste it back on my windows notepad.

I can't copy the file from that server to another due to access restrictions.

Comment: OK, if so is there an easy way to copy a very huge file. I got like 1000 lines.

Comment: if your file is huge the clipboard will fail anyway. When the access restrictions say, that you cannot read the file, you are lost of course. If you cannot copy the file because you can't write the file you must ask yourself, if there is another destination you can write to.

Comment: You could, perhaps, edit the file on the system itself. You then wouldn't need to copy the contents anywhere.

Comment: I just asked a related question since I can't get xclip working when logging into Ubuntu from Git Bash on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60117294/470749

Comment: Exactly same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130968/how-can-i-copy-the-output-of-a-command-directly-into-my-clipboard

Answer (score 148):

### X11

If using X11 (the most common GUI on traditional Unix or Linux based systems), to copy the content of a file to the X11 CLIPBOARD selection without *displaying* it, you can use the `xclip` or `xsel` utility.

```
xclip -sel c < file
```

Or:

```
xsel -b < file
```

to store the content of `file` as the CLIPBOARD X11 selection.

To store the output of a command:

```
mycommand | xclip -sel c
mycommand | xsel -b
```

Note that it should be stored using an UTF-8 encoding or otherwise pasting won't work properly. If the `file` is encoded using an another character set, you should convert to UTF-8 first, like:

```
<file iconv -f latin1 -t utf8 | xclip -sel c
```

for a file encoded in *latin1*/*iso8859-1*.

`xsel` doesn't work with binary data (it doesn't accept null bytes), but `xclip` does.

To store it as a CUT_BUFFER (those are still queried by some applications like `xterm` when nothing claims the CLIPBOARD or PRIMARY X selections and don't need to have a process running to serve it like for selections), though you probably won't want or need to use that nowadays:

```
xprop -root -format CUT_BUFFER0 8s -set CUT_BUFFER0 "$(cat file)"
```

(removes the trailing newline characters from `file`).

### GNU screen

GNU `screen` has the `readbuf` command to slurp the content of a file into its own copy-paste buffer (which you paste with `^A]`). So:

```
screen -X readbuf file
```

### Apple OS/X

Though Apple OS/X *can* use X11. It doesn't by default unless you run a X11 application. You would be able to use `xclip` or `xsel` there as OS/X should synchronise the X11 CLIPBOARD selection with OS/X pasteboard buffers, but that would be a bit of a waste to start the X11 server just for that.

On OS/X, you can use the [`pbcopy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html) command to store arbitrary content into *pasteboard* buffers:

```
pbcopy < file
```

(the file's character encoding is expected to be the locale's one). To store the output of a command:

```
mycommand | pbcopy
```

### Shells

Most shells have their own copy-paste buffers. In emacs mode, cut and copy operations store the copied/cut text onto a stack which you yank/paste with <kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd>, and cycle through with <kbd>Alt+Y</kbd>

#### zsh CUTBUFFER/killring

In `zsh`, the stack is stored in the `$killring` array and the top of the stack in the `$CUTBUFFER` variable though those variables are only available from Zsh Line Editor (zle) widgets and a few specialised widgets are the prefered way to manipulate those.

Because those are only available via the ZLE, doing it with commands is a bit convoluted:

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
zle-line-init() {
  if [ -n "$FILE_TO_COPY" ]; then
    zle copy-region-as-kill $mapfile[$FILE_TO_COPY]
    unset FILE_TO_COPY
  fi
}

zle -N zle-line-init
file-copy() FILE_TO_COPY=$1:A
```

The `zle-line-init` special widget is executed once at the start of each new command prompt. What that means is that the file will only be copied at the next prompt. For instance, if you do:

```
file-copy file; sleep 2
```

The file will only be copied after those 2 seconds.

Comment: I'm facing this error: `Error: Can't open display: (null)`

Comment: Same problem here in fedora 7

Comment: @MarceloFilho, `xclip` and `xsel` are X11 utilities, they manipulate the X11 selections, so can only be used in a X11 environment where `$DISPLAY` is set.

Comment: What if I'm in a docker container :(

Answer (score 3):

[Maybe you wanted to ask this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210615/how-to-copy-file-contents-to-the-local-clipboard-from-a-file-in-a-remote-machine/210619#210619). But any file you want to read must be opened by some system call. If you don't have access to a file, you can't read it. That's the idea of restricted access.

Comment: So whats your actual problem? If you can read but you can't copy, you might not be able to write. But when you want to copy you need to write the data somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps my solution is specific to my setup, but in any rate I'll put it here and see if its helpful for anyone else.

I have ssh access to the (Linux) server that has a file that I'd like to have in my local (OSx) computer's "clipboard" so that I can then paste it locally.

From the *local* machine I issue the following command:

```
$ ssh user@host 'cat /path/to/file/I/want/in/remote/system' | pbcopy
```

Now the contents of the file are in my local buffer and I can paste into an application of my choice. Note that the contents of the file do not appear on the screen when I do this and the content is transmitted via ssh so should be as secure as copying the file via scp (in case there are concerns about privacy/security.)

Answer (score 1):

I installed xclip and created a script named "copy" that takes a filename as its argument.

```
#! /bin/sh -
exec xclip -selection clipboard -i "$@"
```

Example usage:  `copy id_rsa.pub` copies my public key to the clipboard.

Comment: noob question: And where do you put this script? (In which folder?)

Comment: @Pranav anywhere that's in your path (`echo $PATH` to see that list). Personally I added a `bin` directory to my home folder for random scripts like that, and added it to $PATH. That last you can do in .bashrc for example