# How to make a file with content from the clipboard without opening the file?

Tags: clipboard

[Copy the contents of a file into the clipboard without displaying its contents](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211817/copy-the-contents-of-a-file-into-the-clipboard-without-displaying-its-contents)

In the above post they provide a solution (`xsel -b <file`) to copy content from file to clipboard without opening file. I want to get the reverse solution, I have content in clipboard. I want to save the content as a file without opening the file and pasting the content.

Answer (score 15):

`xsel`’s default behaviour depends on whether its input or output is connected to a terminal, so redirecting to and from files typically does the right thing. As mentioned by [codeforester](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/201820/codeforester), the solution in your case is to run

```
xsel -b > file
```

You can make your intent explicit by adding `-o` (when outputting the contents of the clipboard) or `-i` (when inputting to the clipboard). Without these options, if `xsel`’s context is indeterminate (*i.e.* neither standard input or standard output are connected to a terminal), it behaves in `-o` mode: `xsel -b < /dev/null > file` works as you’d expect, but `xsel -b < file > /dev/null` doesn’t.

You can also use `xclip` to copy the clipboard’s contents to a file:

```
xclip -sel c -o > file
```

`xclip` can additionally request specific versions of the clipboard’s contents (known as targets), depending on the selection’s owner; for example, if you copied text from a web browser, you could retrieve it as HTML using

```
xclip -sel -c -o -t text/html > file
```

The special `TARGETS` target will list the available targets:

```
xclip -sel -c -o -t TARGETS
```