# use less on content in clipboard

Tags: less, clipboard

I copied some text and want to search through it using `less`. I wonder how I can directly use `less` on my clipboard content without having it saved first into a file or being `echo`d etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more low-tech way:

You've copied something, right?  So if you hit Shift-Insert or whatever, it will paste, right?

```
$ cat | less
```

Now press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Voila!  You can now scroll up and down and search and do whatever you want with `less`, operating on the clipboard text you pasted in.

Note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will not work to terminate the input to `cat` in this case.  I'm not sure why, but it didn't on FreeBSD nor on Ubuntu.

Comment: the simpliest way and no need of any tools

Answer (score 5):

Use [xclip](https://github.com/astrand/xclip) or [xsel](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/) (which should available on any Linux distribution and in BSD ports).

For the X11 selection that is automatically copied when you select something with the mouse:

```
xsel | less
xclip -o | less
```

For the X11 clipboard that is copied explicitly (typically with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>):

```
xsel -b | less
xclip -o -selection c | less
```

On macOS, use `pbpaste`.

```
pbpaste | less
```

See [Copy the contents of a file into the clipboard without displaying its contents](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211817/copy-the-contents-of-a-file-into-the-clipboard-without-displaying-its-contents) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Under X11 this won't work because of the way the clipboards are integrated.

First of all, there are two clipboards in use:

1. Something you selected
2. Something you copied with a hotkey (like ctrl + c)

Programs can use both or either of those clipboards.

The whole process works a bit like this:

```
Client A                    X Server                    Client B
----------------------------------------------------------------

(1) |  I own selection FOO!    |
    |  ------------------->    |


                               |  Write sel. FOO to BAR!  | (2)
                               |  <---------------------  |


    | Write sel. FOO to BAR!   |
    | <---------------------   |


    |     Here is FOO.
    | -------------------------:----------------------->  |


                                     Okay, got it.        |
    | <------------------------:------------------------  |
```

([source](https://www.uninformativ.de/blog/postings/2017-04-02/0/POSTING-en.html))

If you want to use clipboard content in your terminal workflow, you could use something like [xclip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip) and alias them to a command of your choice.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to in the first sentence, but the existence of xclip shows that it's possible.

Comment: it works if there is a program acting as someone pasting the stuff and providing it in a file or some other way